# Are there good reasons not to exploit '#!/bin/make -f' at the top of a makefile to give an executable makefile?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, makefile

Mostly for my amusement, I created a `makefile` in my `$HOME/bin` directory called `rebuild.mk`, and made it executable, and the first lines of the file read:

```
#!/bin/make -f
#
# Comments on what the makefile is for

...

all: ${SCRIPTS} ${LINKS} ...

...
```

I can now type:

```
rebuild.mk
```

and this causes `make` to execute.

What are the reasons for not exploiting this on a permanent basis, other than this:

- The makefile is tied to a single directory, so it really isn't appropriate in my main `bin` directory.

Has anyone ever seen the trick exploited before?

---

Collecting some comments, and providing a bit more background information.

1. Norman Ramsey reports that this technique is used in Debian; that is interesting to know.  Thank you.
2. I agree that typing 'make' is more idiomatic.
3. However, the scenario (previously unstated) is that my $HOME/bin directory already has a cross-platform main makefile in it that is the primary maintenance tool for the 500+ commands in the directory.
4. However, on one particular machine (only), I wanted to add a makefile for building a special set of tools.  So, those tools get a special makefile, which I called `rebuild.mk` for this question (it has another name on my machine).
5. I do get to save typing '`make -f rebuild.mk`' by using '`rebuild.mk`' instead.
6. Fixing the position of the `make` utility is problematic across platforms.
7. The `#!/usr/bin/env make -f` technique is likely to work, though I believe the official rules of engagement are that the line must be less than 32 characters and may only have one argument to the command.
8. @dF comments that the technique might prevent you passing arguments to make.  That is not a problem on my Solaris machine, at any rate.  The three different versions of 'make' I tested (Sun, GNU, mine) all got the extra command line arguments that I type, including options ('-u' on my home-brew version) and targets 'someprogram' and macros CC='cc' WFLAGS=-v (to use a different compiler and cancel the GCC warning flags which the Sun compiler does not understand).

#### I would not advocate this as a general technique.

As stated, it was mostly for my amusement.  I may keep it for this particular job; it is most unlikely that I'd use it in distributed work.  And if I did, I'd supply and apply a '`fixin`' script to fix the pathname of the interpreter; indeed, I did that already on my machine.  That script is a relic from the first edition of the Camel book ('Programming Perl' by Larry Wall).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem with this for generally distributable Makefiles is that the location of `make` is not always consistent across platforms. Also, some systems might require an alternate name like `gmake`.

Of course one can always run the appropriate command manually, but this sort of defeats the whole purpose of making the Makefile executable.

Comment: Exactly.  On my system for example, make is in /usr/bin.

Comment: But you're still no worse off than you were to start with.

Answer (score 5):

I've **seen this trick used before** in the `debian/rules` file that is part of every Debian package.

Answer (score 3):

To address the problem of `make` not always being in the same place (on my system for example it's in `/usr/bin`), you could use

```
#!/usr/bin/env make -f
```

if you're on a UNIX-like system.

Another problem is that by using the Makefile this way you cannot override variables, by doing, for example `make CFLAGS=...`.

Comment: You can override - and provide other arguments on the command line.  At least, that's what my experiments show.

Comment: Separately, officially, you can provide one argument (not two as shown).  And the whole command line string has to be under 32 characters, I believe.

Comment: If env isn't in that place then you're using a Linux that is inventing problems for itself.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to pass arguments, like to any other hash-bang script? Note that -f is used, so the script file that the kernel supplies will be taken as the argument to -f, and other arguments can be processed: targets, variable assignments, other make options like `-k` for keep going, etc.

Comment: Passing more than one argument has failed on at least one OS I've used, I think it was Linux.

Answer (score 2):

"make" is shorter than "./Makefile", so I don't think you're buying anything.

Comment: True: but rebuild.mk is shorter than 'make -f rebuild.mk' so I do gain something.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I would not do this is that typing "make" is more idiomatic to building Makefile based projects.  Imagine if every project you built you had to search for the differently named makefile someone created instead of just typing "make && make install".

Comment: The usecase for this would probably not be so much a new command for building projects, rather looking at make as yet another language for writing scripts.  I can see myself using make instead of bash, if my script contains a lot of if [ file.x -nt -file.y ].

Comment: Also, in my particular scenario, I have a cross-platform main makefile already in the directory, and I wanted a separate one for the particular machine and particular set of commands - hence rebuild.mk.

Comment: But I agree - typing 'make' is more idiomatic.  This just saves me typing 'make -f rebuild.mk'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shell alias for this too.

Comment: @PEZ: yes, I could.  It would be one of very, very few aliases that I have, though; I grew up before they were routinely available, and generally uses scripts instead of aliases (not least because scripts work regardless of which shell I'm using).  In other words, I wouldn't use an alias for this.

Comment: I think a script is good for this. It's what I most often use too. I just pointed out that you *cold* use a shell alias too. Could be good to know for some of the people who Google up your question.

Answer (score 0):

We can look at this another way: is it a good idea to design a language whose interpreter looks for a fixed filename if you don't give it one? What if `python` looked for `Pythonfile` in the absence of a script name? ;)

You don't need such a mechanism in order to have a convention based around a known name. Example: Autoconf's `./configure` script.