# How to write a Makefile to copy scripts to server

Tags: bash, makefile

After I finish writing scripts on my local machine, I need to copy them in the cluster to execute the codes. For example, I want to copy all the matlab files in my current directory in a directory at the server id@server.

Can anyone help to write a very basic Makefile to fulfill this purpose?

Thanks a lot!

John

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to have others write scripts for you; [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I didn't mean writing a script. I only would like to have a top script which I could follow and modify.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an adaptation of Jens's answer, together with my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395234/any-interesting-uses-of-makefiles-to-share/48808690#48808690), that takes advantage of the capabilities of Make to only copy across those files that have been modified since the last time you copied the files to the server.  That way, if you have hundreds of `.m` files and you modify one of them, you won't copy all of them across to the server.

It makes use of an empty hidden file, `.last_push`, that serves only to record (through its own timestamp) the time at which we last copied files to the server.

```
FILES = $(shell find . -name *.m)
SCP = scp id@server:path/relative/to/your/serverhomedir
LAST_PUSH = .last_push

.PHONY : push
push : $(LAST_PUSH)

$(LAST_PUSH) : $(FILES)
    $(SCP) $?
    touch $(LAST_PUSH)
```

Run this with `make` or `make push`.  The key is the variable `$?`, which is populated with the list of all prerequisites that are newer than the target - in this case, the list of `.m` files that have been modified more recently than the last push.

Comment: Doesn't `$(SCP) $?` here expand to `scp $external_url_with_path $modified_file1 $modified_file2` and so on? Because if so, it doesn't push - it pulls. Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

How do you copy files to the server? Assuming you have ssh/scp available:

```
FILES = file1 file2 *.matlab
copy:
     scp $(FILES) id@server:path/relative/to/your/serverhomedir
```

Run with

```
$ make copy
```

As a shell script, it could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -- file1 file2 *.matlab
scp "$@" id@server:path/relative/to/your/serverhomedir
```

Don't forget to `chmod u+x yourscript`.

Comment: Jens, if you write the makefile this way, then there is no point in using a makefile at all - your makefile is really a shell script, and the script should be used instead.

Comment: Suppse I write a file named copyscript with contents:                            FILES = file1 file2 *.matlab
copy:
     scp $(FILES) id@server:path/relative/to/your/serverhomedir                Then run the script as ./copyscript?                                        Is this the right way to go? Thanks!