# Makefile: No rules to make target files in servers

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, scp

I want to create a makefile that syncs files from a server to my local PC. With this makefile I want to only copy from my server to my local computer those files that were modified. To do that I did a makefile based in boths answers from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395234/any-interesting-uses-of-makefiles-to-share/48808690#48808690) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509718/how-to-write-a-makefile-to-copy-scripts-to-server). This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
FILES = *.csv
SCP = scp id@server:~/Results
LAST_SYNC = .last_sync


.PHONY: sync

sync : $(LAST_SYNC)

$(LAST_SYNC) : $(FILES)
    $(SCP) $?
    touch $(LAST_SYNC)
```

If I run `make` it appears the following error:

> make: *** No rule to make target '*.csv', needed by '.last_sync'.  Stop.

Are there any way to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I've just changed the problem with the `FILES` variable according to G.M.'s suggestion:
`FILES := $(wildcard *.csv)`
Now the following error appears:

```
scp id@server:~/Results results1.csv results2.csv results3.csv
results3.csv: Not a directory 
make: *** [Makefile:13: .last_sync] Error 1
```

Comment: `make` doesn't do automatic filename globbing.  Try `FILES := $(wildcard *.csv)` instead.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work because is looking to my local files. Now it executes:
`scp id@server:~/Results results1.csv results2.csv results3.csv....`

Comment: Read the `scp` manual page. If you want to copy the local `*.csv` files to a remote location, the destination goes _last_ on the command line.

Comment: True. But the problem is that I want that makefile identifies all the files to sync in my server anc copy to my local PC. Now I've just change the rule to `$(SCP)$? ./` and only checks the local files.

Comment: If you want remote file globbing that's different.  You could use `ssh`, but why not just perform the whole sync operation using `rsync` with something like `rsync -vaz --include '*.csv' --exclude '*' id@server:~/Results ./` ?

Comment: How exactly do you expect make to know whether the local files are out of date or not?  The only way it can know is by examining the timestamps on the remote files.  There's no facility in make that will allow it to ssh to another system, check the timestamps on files on that other system, and use that to decide whether the local files are out of date or not.

Comment: @G.M. Because I've never heard about it. I've just test it and works well if I remove the `--exclude '*'`